# this application has no explicit mapping for /error white label error

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, tomcat

this application has no explicit mapping for /error
still displaying after making sure the main application is in the right package

made sure the application and service and controller are in right package tried using component scan as well as check dependancies

https://ibb.co/n7vhZLD : file/package order

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
}

}
```

Dependacies

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0     http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>demo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>demo</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<packaging>war</packaging>
```

Controller

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Hashtable;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import model.Car;
import service.CarService;

@CrossOrigin
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/car")
public class CarController {

@Autowired
CarService cs;

@RequestMapping("/all")
public ArrayList<Car> getAll() {
    return cs.getAll();
}

@RequestMapping("{id}")
public Car getCar(@PathVariable("id") String id) {
    return cs.getCar(id);
}
}
```

Comment: obviously there is no mapping for url, that you are trying to access. Please provide your controller code, configuration and url you are trying to access.

Comment: added the controller code

Comment: using localhost:8080/car/all and/or localhost:8080/car/1

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Have you tried using @RequestMapping("/{id}")?

Comment: @Deadpool my question is what is the solution for getting " this application has no explicit mapping for /error"

Comment: @mate00 still got the same issue

Comment: check my answer @christopherfeghali you need to add `@ComponentScan` on main class by specifying packages

Comment: Please post your `Car` class.

Comment: I used component scan before but it seems i was not specifying the correct packages (instead calling the classes) @Deadpool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at you package structure Main class `DemoApplication` is in `com.example.demo` package

```
package com.example.demo;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {
```

And `CarService` is in `package service.CarService`

```
import service.CarService;

@Autowired
CarService cs;
```

In the same way `CarController` might be in different package which are not in organised structure.

By default `@SpringBootApplication` perform component scan scanning from the package of the class that declares this annotation. Since your `service` and `controller` classes are not in sub packages of base package you need to explicitly add`@ComponentScan`

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({"service","controller"})
public class DemoApplication {
```